# Windows でパス ~/.emacs.d/backups/ とはどこのこと？

Tags: windows, emacs, elisp

「emacs実践入門」という本を参考にして`init.el`に設定を記述していっているのですが、

```
;; バックアップとオートセーブファイルを~/.emacs.d/backups/へ集める
(add-to-list 'backup-directory-alist
             (cons "." "~/.emacs.d/backups/"))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,(expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/backups/") t)))
```

という記述があり、上記の通りに`init.el`に記載したのですが、C-x C-eで上記を評価してもバックアップとオートセーブファイルがうまく`.emacs.d/backups`下に集約されませんでした。

パスの設定についてよく理解していないこともあるのですが、
`~/.emacs.d/backups/`
の"~"というのは、どこのパスを指しているのでしょうか?

現在Cドライブ直下に`emacs/.emacs.d`というフォルダを作成して、そこにinit.elを置いているのですが、その場合"~"は`C:\emacs`を指すのでしょうか？

OSはwindows10です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~`は主にUnix系OSで使用される表現で、今現在ログインしているユーザ(=自分自身)の**ホームディレクトリ**を指します。Windowsの場合は`C:\Users\ユーザー名\`がそれにあたりますが、環境変数`HOME`が設定されていない場合には代わりに`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\`を参照している可能性もあるので、下記のサイトを参考に「ユーザー環境変数」として`HOME`に`%USERPROFILE%`を設定してみてください。

参考：
[Windows 7 における Emacs のセットアップ作業のメモ](http://yoshiiz.blog129.fc2.com/blog-entry-794.html)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。現状環境変数`HOME`は`C:\emacs`に設定しています。
となると`~/.emacs.d/backups/`は`C:/emacs/.emacs.d/backups/`を指しているということでしょうか？

Comment: 自分で変更されているのであればその理解で合っていると思います。後はチルダを使わず`C:\～`のWindowsで見慣れたパスで記述してしまう方法もアリかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
チルダを使わない方法で記述したところ, うまくいきました。
ありがとうございました。